# what's wrong with this trigger(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Schema:

```
Customer(cid, cname, caddress, cphone, balance)
Movie(mid, title, genre, year)
Branch(bid, bname, baddress)
Copy(copyid, mid, bid)
Rented(cid, copyid, outdate, returndate, cost)
```

Write statements for updating the database when a customer returns a movie, that is, for updating the rental record and reducing the credit balance in the customer record. Assume that the cost of the rental is $3 for the first day plus $1 for each additional day.

trigger I wrote:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_returndate AFTER UPDATE ON rented 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (new.returndate is not null)
    THEN
        UPDATE customer
        SET balance = balance - (3 + (new.returndate - old.outdate))                   
        where cid = new.cid;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error reported: none 
Problem : Running endlessly

Comment: how do you know this is the part that gets stuck?

Comment: Do you have triggers on table 'customer'? How many rows do your tables hold? How do you know it is endless and not just taking a (very) long time?